# Units of measure do not match in spring formula

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, spring, dimensional-analysis, si-units

I am reading about harmonic oscillators and I found that this equation describes the equilibrium of a mass $M$ attached to a spring with stiffness $k$.

$$Mg = kx_0=0$$

- $M$ is the mass, which is expressed in $Kg$
- $g$ is the gravity attraction, which is expressed in $m^3 Kg^{-1}s^{-2}$ or equivalently $Nm^2Kg^{-2}$ using $N=Kg m s^{-2}$.
- $k$ is the stiffness expressed in $N/m$.
- $x_0$ is a position, which is expressed in $m$.

However, by putting these units of measure together we obtain

$$\frac{m^3}{s^2} = \frac{Kg}{s^2}m $$

what did I do wrong?

Comment: The units of $g$, the *acceleration* due to gravity are $m/s^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"$g$" is the acceleration due to gravity, with units of $\frac{m}{s^2}$. You may have confused it with the universal gravitational constant (represented by "$G$"), which has units of $\frac{N.m^2}{kg^2}$

The units of $Mg$ is $\frac{kg.m}{s^2} = N$, while $kx$ has units of $\frac{N}{m}.m = N$, so the units do match.

Hope this helps